# Isomorphism of vector spaces - is 1:1 enough?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-space-isomorphism

From 'Functional Anaylsis' by Bachman

> If the linear transformation is 1:1, it is called an isomorphism

Is this right? I thought an isomorphism was a morhpism that admitted an inverse. Unless we also know that this linear transformation is onto, how can we know that is has an inverse?

Comment: Indeed, it also requires surjective. But the term 1:1 is (in rare cases) used to mean bijective (though this is usually only in the phrase "1:1 correspondence". Also, if the vector spaces are of the same finite dimension, then injective implies surjective.

Comment: 1:1 is a somewhat ambiguous expression. You take to mean *injective*, while the author apparently means *bijective*.

Comment: (this is a good reason why one should just entirely avoid the terms 1:1 and onto and stick with the unambiguous and harder to miss injective and surjective).

Comment: In the previous page he defines 1:1 as "distinct points in the domain have distinct images". 

@TobiasKildetoft I agree, much confusion would be spared

Answer (score 1):

If a linear transformation is one-to-one, then it has some range $R$ which is likely a subspace of a Euclidean space $\Bbb{R}^n$. While it might not be onto with $\Bbb{R}^n$, it is definitely onto with $R$ and thus the linear transformation is an isomorphism between the domain and $R$.

Comment: Since OP mentions 'functional analysis' I think it's very unlikely it is onto a subspace of finite dimensional space

Comment: @user340297 note that this is just the introduction (background material)